# Are the .min of versions files used when `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true`?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundle, bundling-and-minification

Does specifying `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` minify all `CSS` and `JS` files in a bundle, or are the available **min** versions of files used?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One has nothing to do with the other. `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` exists merely to provide a way to force bundling in development, where it's disabled by default. In production, it's enabled by default, and unnecessary to specify anything for `EnableOptimizations`. Either way, though, it only determines whether bundling will happen or not, not *how* it will occur or what will happen as a result.

That said, the standard behavior is to bundle but *not* minify anything that has a companion file with in the form of `[filename].min.[ext]`. It will simply take the minified source file and dump its content into the bundle. If there is no companion file, then the original file will be minified first before bundling.

Comment: Does the companion file have to be in the same folder?

Comment: @RuudLenders: Sorry, never saw your comment before now. Yes, the bundle should reference the non-minified filename, and if it detects a file in the same directory with `[filename].min.[ext]` format, it will then use that instead. If you reference the minimized version directly, it can be anywhere you like, but it will always then utilize that file, which might make development work more difficult.